# Problem with wi-fi: apt-get cannot connect to servers

Tags: networking, drivers, apt

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 and wi-fi module wasn't used. I installed a driver and wi-fi is working now, but apt can't connect to archive.ubuntu.com. However when I use wired connection it works.

I don't understand how to fix it. Can anybody help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].